# Give access to laptop's internal HDD to other Windows users

Tags: windows, security, filesystems, file-transfer, ownership

I replaced my laptops HDD with SSD, I have tons of data on that HDD and I use that drive as external backup, I tried to access it from Windows 7 PC and I had no problems, here is picture how properties of that drive show up on that Windows 7, in the owner tab current Windows 7 user is set.

[image: here is an image]

I want to access this HDD files in Windows 10 laptop via USB to SATA cable. It does open up, but when opening any file its throws "Access denied".

The solutions I found is to change Ownership of that HDD, but I think it would be huge task to process as there are tons of small files on that drive, and also I want to access that HDD from both, win7 pc and win10 laptop anytime I want.

Is there any other simpler way? How can I remove that restriction just to give access to my HDD to any other Windows user?

Comment: If the hard drive is still bootable, put  it back in your computer temporarily and move the files to c:\temp .  Then remove the drive and restore the SSD. Anyone should be able to read the files.

Comment: @John nope drive is not bootable anymore I have erased all windows files from it